# Block Collision Code Troubleshooting

Tags: java

I'm finishing up a coding assignment that requires me to set an array of blocks in motion, bouncing off of the window and each other, but unfortunately I'm totally lost as to where to go next. Any help would be appreciated (still getting the hang of coding, so I'm looking for all the help possible). Specifically, I need the rectangles to appear first, and then troubleshoot movement, and finally help with collision detection.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Driver implements ActionListener
{
    private JFrame window;
    private Timer timer;
    private ChaseBlock[] blocks = new ChaseBlock[15];
    // constants for graphics
    private final int windowSize = 500;
    private final int blockSize = 20;
    /**
     * Simple initiating main().
     *
     * @param args Not used.
     */
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Driver d = new Driver();
        d.createWindow();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the basic graphical objects.
     */
    private void createWindow()
    {
        // create the window
        window = new JFrame( "The Great Chase" );
        window.setVisible( true );
        window.setLayout( null );
        window.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.white );
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        window.setLocation( 50, 50 );
        window.setSize(
                       windowSize + window.getInsets().left + window.getInsets().right,
                       windowSize + window.getInsets().top + window.getInsets().bottom );
        window.setResizable( false );
        window.repaint();

        timer = new Timer(10, this);
        timer.start();
        blocks[1].setBackground(Color.blue);
        window.repaint();
        addBlocks();


    }

    private void addBlocks() {
        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
            int x = i * blockSize + 10 * (i +1);
            blocks[i] = new ChaseBlock(x, windowSize / x - blockSize / 2, blockSize, windowSize);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
            window.add(blocks[i]);

        }
    }

    private void animate() {
        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
            blocks[i].move();

            for (int b1 = 0; b1 < blocks.length; b1++)
                for (int b2 = 0; b2 < blocks.length; b2++)
                    if (b1 != b2)
                        blocks[b1].checkCollision(blocks[b2]);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        animate();
    }
}
```

This is the driver class that we use, with a Rectangle class also. Near to the bottom, the goal is to add the rectangles and make them move. My problem here is that the rectangles do not show up whatsoever or move.

```
import java.awt.Color;
public class ChaseBlock extends Rectangle {
    private int dX, dY;
    private int windowWidth = 500;
    private int windowHeight = 500;

    public ChaseBlock(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        super(x, y, w, h );
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            dX = -1;
            dY = -1;
            setBackground(Color.green);
        } else
            dX = 1;
            dY = 1;
            setBackground(Color.blue);
    }

    public void move() {
        setLocation(getX(), getY() + 5);
        if(getX() < 0 || getY() + getWidth() >= windowWidth) {
            dX = dX * -1;
        }
        if (getY() < 0 || getY() + getHeight() >= windowHeight) {
            dY = dY * -1;
        }
    }

    public void checkCollision(ChaseBlock blocks) {
        boolean up = false;
        boolean down = false; 
        boolean left = false;
        boolean right = false; 
        boolean hit = false;

    }

}
```

This is my class to define the movement and everything else. My problems here are that I need to use the checkCollision method to manage the collisions between the blocks themselves and the window, and in addition set colors for all the blocks.

Comment: Try to ask a specific question that will help you solve your problem.  Think about exactly what you are having trouble with and ask a question about that single thing.  This question is too broad.  Also try to include only as much code as is necessary to illustrate the problem instead of dumping your entire project... this will help you to get more useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the first condition for collision checks with window edges is incorrect. It should be

```
if(getX() < 0 || getX() + getWidth() >= windowWidth)
```

To detect collisions between two Axis Aligned Bounding Boxes (which is what you have as `Rectangle`s), you just have to check whether the first's min and max points (x,y and x+h, y+h) are inside the second as follows:

```
if(a.x + a.h < b.x or a.x > b.x + b.h) return false;
if(a.y + a.h < b.y or a.y > b.y + b.h) return false;
return true;
```

If you want to find out which face (or which direction) the collision takes place on, you'll have to use the more long and slightly more complicated Separating Axis Theorem.